# Framework init param is not a member type of class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, observer-pattern

I am working on one framework and it is working fine if it is directly connected to the test app in the same project. But when I build it for release and implement it into another test app it shows me this error:

`Failed to build module 'MySDK' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug`

After some digging, I get an error message `... is not a member type of class ...`
And the problem is in the initial parameter and in my observer

this is my entry / init  class:

```
public class MySdk {
...
    public init(eventObserver: MyResultObserver){ // this observer is a problem maker
        EventObserver.shared.attach(eventObserver)
    };
 
    public init(){}
...
```

and this is how my `MyResultObserver` looks like (it is in a separate file)

```
import Foundation

public protocol MyResultObserver: AnyObject {

    func success(successMessage: String)
    func error(errorMessage: String)
}
```

and extension:

```
import Foundation

extension MyResultObserver: NSCopying {

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return self
    }
}
```

How should it work (it is working in a test project in that SDK folder)

```
import UIKit
import MySdk


class ViewController: UIViewController, MyResultObserver { // added observer here 
    func success(successMessage: String) {} // observer function 1
    
    func error(errorMessage: String) {} // observer function 2

...
    
    @IBAction func openSdkClick(){
        let myAwesomeSdk = MySDK(eventObserver: self) // init my sdk with observer 
    }
    
}
```

But the problem is when I implement it like this into the test app (as cocoa pod) it will give me an error above. I try to remove this observer parameter and SDK works fine.
How can I make my observer visible? Should I put it into headers somewhere? any hint?

### UPDATE

when I am trying to use that framework I can jump to the definition and this is result:

```
// swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
// swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 5.7.1 (swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3 clang-1400.0.29.51)
// swift-module-flags: -target x86_64-apple-ios15.5-simulator -enable-objc-interop -enable-library-evolution -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -module-name WalleePaymentSdk
// swift-module-flags-ignorable: -enable-bare-slash-regex
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import Swift
import UIKit
@_exported import MySDK
import _Concurrency
import _StringProcessing
public protocol PaymenResultObserver : AnyObject {
  func success(successMessage: Swift.String)
  func error(errorMessage: Swift.String)
}
public typealias callback = (Swift.String) -> Swift.Void
open class MySDK : MySDK.PaymenResultObserver {
  public func success(successMessage: Swift.String)
  public func error(errorMessage: Swift.String)
  public init(eventObserver: @escaping MySDK.callback)
  public func launchPayment(transactionId: Swift.String, token: Swift.String, rootController: UIKit.UIViewController)
  public func close()
  @objc deinit
}
```

I did some modification to the code I put `Observer` inside SDK and I am trying to access the function `callback` which  shuld be define by SDK consumer ... but  that observer get this error:

```
'Observer' is not a member type of class 'MySdk.MySdk'
```

and callback

```
'callback' is not a member type of class 'MySDK.MySDK'
```

problem is this line:
`open class MySDK : MySDK.PaymenResultObserver` 
and this line
  `public init(eventObserver: @escaping MySDK.callback)`

both elements are there but I am accessing them inside the SDK and SDK can not inherit from them itself